# General Problem: No Sound, can't reduce Brightness. lspci attached

Tags: 10.04, sound, brightness

I've installed Ubuntu Lucid in my lappy (Compaq CQ42 173TU) before with Wubi, the sound and brightness problems were still there. I thought it was a problem due to installing through Wubi. 
So I installed it again from Boot. But the problem persists. There is No sound at all, but the OS seems like that it has no problem at all.
And Also, I cannot reduce brightness. The brightness applet says "Cannot get laptop panel brightness" ..

Here is the the output by `lspci` -

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

And also, I cannot check the temperature. There is no folder inside `thermal_zone` .. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I wonder... how exactly were you trying to change the brightness?  With function keys or something built into your system?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the sound problem in my compaq cq42-121la.

Adding the ppa (via command line):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the linux-alsa-driver-modules package (via command line):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer I'm fond of, but you might try a 10.10 livecd. The links below show your chipset is generally supported, but I don't see your laptop model certified. Google reports many others are in your same boat. I'll see what else I can find tomorrow, or maybe someone will beat me to the answer.

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/model/pci:3B56:8086-AUDIO

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/search?form.search_text=Intel+Corporation+5+Series%2F3400+Series+&search=Search

Comment: Upgrade is always an option. I'll do the same. But was checking if it can be done without upgrading. It'll take some time to get an maverick disc.. :-/